# Existence of an isolated point such that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 0$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $u$ be a smooth real valued function on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is it possible for the derivative $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ to have an isolated zero? I think the answer is no. Here is my reasoning:

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$. If $x$ is a critical point of $u$, then I think by the Poincare index theorem there must exist a point in every ball around $x$ such that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$ so $x$ is not an isolated critical point of $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$. Now if $x$ is not a critical point of $u$, then locally around $x$, the level set of $u$ looks like a bunch of parallel curves "foliating" the ball. Then there should be a point in every ball around $x$ such that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$ which means that $x$ is not an isolated critical point of $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$.

Is this correct? Or is there some obvious counterexample I'm not seeing?

My original question was to determine whether or not the directional derivative (in a particular direction) of a smooth function can have isolated critical points, which I believe is equivalent to the above.

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: The function $u(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ looks like a counterexample. Only at $(x,y)=(0,0)$, the derivative $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$. Or do I miss something? Besides, your notation is a bit confusing: $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$, but $y\in\mathbb{R}$ is the second coordinate.

Comment: @Ern, in your example, that derivative is $2y$, which is zero at $(x,0)$ for all $x$. But there is an idea there; if $u=x^2y+y^3$, then the $y$-derivative is $x^2+3y^2$, which has an isolated zero at the origin.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson. Aha, I get it. For some reason I was thinking of the function $y \mapsto \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ (with $x$ fixed) and not $(x,y)\mapsto \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$. Thanks for clarifying this!

Comment: I think then  I need to add the condition that the critical points of $u$ need to be nondegenerate.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "nondegenerate", Vishnu?

Comment: Maybe I used the wrong terminology, but I meant that the eigenvalues of the Hessian matrix of $u$ are nonzero.